# C# NetTopology CoordinateValue Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, odata, nettopologysuite

I try to make an OData-API supporting spatial Queries. I build my model, with a database-first approach (from PostGresql) including a PostGIS - Column. It seems to import it correctly, having this in DBContext:

```
            entity.Property(e => e.Geom)
                .HasColumnName("geom")
                .HasColumnType("geometry(Point,4326)");
```

And in the model it is like this:

```
    public Point Geom { get; set; }
```

So, when making the call the following happens: All the Data are loaded from the Database, but the Geometry has an infinite Loop like this:

[image: Infinite Loop]

And i have no idea why it's happening.

Any Advice, how to fix this and where the problem might lie, would be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: I don't know anything about NetTopology, but if you think this problem is being caused by your Property Geom, you could try explicitly defining the get and set methods.

Comment: hi, i think thats just normal.
the coordinatevalue property just returns itself which results in a endless loop when you click through it in the debugger. its not there in the data.

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer The problem is, when returning the set with Odata it also loops in the response JSON....so it's not just there which is the problem.

Comment: after looking more into your screenshot, the Property CoordinateValue of the Geom class looks strange to me. What type is `CoordinateValue` of? Can you post the class? Also, your odata request and metadata.xml?